# How add a human signature to a PDF which is captured from a signature-pad and set it to the PDF using Java & iTEXT7?

Tags: java, itext

How add a human signature to a PDF which is captured from a signature-pad and set it to the PDF using Java & iTEXT7 ?

Comment: In what format does your signature pad provide the signature? If it is a regular bitmap image, simply add that bitmap like any other bitmap to your pdf.

Comment: What did you try until now? Provide some code and more information to your problem!